# Group and concatenate DataTable with no unique identifier

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I'm trying to group data in a list of objects in order to create EmailItem items to send however cannot figure out how to group and concatenate the data required.

Essentially, the e-mail to be generated should be a combination of attachments which are required on the e-mail but also the group of recipients of the e-mail.

To explain it visually, this is an example set of objects with which I'm working:

[image: Current Data]

What I'm trying to achieve, based on the above, is as follows:

[image: Required Data]

For reference, in the list with which I'm currently working, each of the records in the table represents an instance of NormalEmailItem within `List<NormalEmailItem>`; I'm therefore looking to end up with a final `List<NormalEmailItem>` with the DEV_ID, CONTACT, EMAIL and ATTACHMENT fields as outlined in my second image.

Been thinking on this for a while now and trying alternatives without getting anywhere, so any suggestions are welcome. I've been trying to achieve this via a combination of LINQ statements but cannot seem to construct one that does all the 'grouping' I need in one go.

EDIT: The data in my tables was ambiguous; this is now corrected.

Comment: To me, it is totally unclear on what criteria you group the items in the first table in order to produce the second table. Could you add those criteria to the question?

Comment: My perception of the issue was that the criteria upon which the records were to be grouped was what I was trying to establish but to try and answer your question, the general criteria is that for each set of CONTACT records, group the DEV_ID and ATTACHMENT records and concatenate them. So if a single CONTACT is the sole record for a DEV_ID, group the DEV_ID and ATTACHMENT records against that CONTACT; however if there are multiple CONTACT records for a single DEV_ID, group the CONTACT records. Thinking about it that way, I wonder if it would be it better to have 2 sets of data?

Comment: Unfortunately it would seem I can't answer my own question just yet so I will need to leave this here prior to doing so. Having looked into this some more, I do not believe that the data I have in the table is appropriate to handle in the way I required and that it would be more manageable to split this out into two sets of data, as they require different grouping. I have however, for reference, raised this as a separate question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056338/c-sharp-datatable-group-by-multiple-columns-and-concatenate-strings)

Comment: You need to group by the "DEV_ID" and Attachment.  So in linq it is GroupBy(x => new object[] {x.Dev_D, x.Attachment}).  If you were using a DataTable then it would be : GroupBy(x => new object[] {x.Field<int>("Dev_D"), x.Field<String>("Attachment")})