# Group DataTable by multiple columns and concatenate strings

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have seen quite a few answers to this question however have unfortunately not been able to contextualise them to my specific scenario, as when I try and concatenate strings in a grouping LINQ statement, I am restricted to an extension overload on `String.Join<>` which just does not seem to work.

Essentially, I have two DataTables in code, each with four records (all strings). I need to group by two of the columns, whilst then concatenating the other two fields with a ', ' separator.

The basis for the grouping is the same for the two tables however groups on different sets of columns, so I am assuming I can apply the solution to one instance to the other as well.

I have the following DataTable in code:

[image: Single Contact Multiple References Current]

I need to group this DataTable by CONTACT and by EMAIL, whilst concatenating REFERENCE and ATTACHMENT with a ', ' separator, to produce the following DataSet:

[image: Single Contact Multiple References Required]

I then have a second DataTable, which I need to group by REFERENCE and by ATTACHMENT, whilst concatenating CONTACT and EMAIL with a ', ' separator. The DataSet would currently contain the following data:

[image: Single Reference Multiple Contacts Current]

What I am trying to achieve with this set is a DataTable with the following information:

[image: Single Reference Multiple Contacts Required]

Comment: can you show the linq code that you are using to do the group by with the DataTable..? also check out this previous posting as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472005/efficient-datatable-group-by

Comment: @MethodMan I think this was one of the solutions at which I was looking however that only groups by a single column; when I involve multiple grouping columns, appears to require a different syntax. Here's the LINQ code I'm using though: `var FinalisedSingleContactMultipleReferences = from row in SingleContactMultipleReferences.AsEnumerable() group row by new { CONTACT = row.Field<string>("CONTACT"), EMAIL = row.Field<string>("EMAIL") } into grp select new { REFERENCE = grp.Join<", ", REFERENCE>, CONTACT = grp.Key.CONTACT, EMAIL = grp.Key.EMAIL, ATTACHMENT = grp.Join<", ", ATTACHMENT>}`

Comment: @Your_Unequal - In your above query, `grp.Join` is incorrect as it is required to join two entities. You need `String.Join` instead as I have mentioned in the answer. Simply replace your `REFERENCE = grp.Join<", ", REFERENCE>` with `REFERENCE = String.Join(",",grp.Select(z => z.Field<string>("REFERENCE")))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following query is giving me the expected output:-

```
var result = dt1.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(x => new { Contact = x.Field<string>("CONTACT"), 
                            Email = x.Field<string>("EMAIL") })
        .Select(x => new 
           {
               REFERENCE = String.Join(",",x.Select(z => z.Field<string>("REFERENCE"))),
               CONTACT = x.Key.Contact,
               EMAIL = x.Key.Email,
               ATTACHMENT = String.Join(",",x.Select(z => z.Field<string>("ATTACHMENT")))
           });
```

Output:

[image]

This query will return anonymous type and not a DataTable. If you want DataTable as output then you will have to create one using `foreach` loop or you can use `CopyToDataTable` method by implementing the extension method mentioned on [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx).

Similarily, you can query the second DataTable.

Comment: This worked perfectly, many thanks. Also thanks for pointing out the nature of the issue (with `grp.Join` instead of `String.Join` being used).